# Fail to add amplitude damping error to NoiseModel

Tags: qiskit, programming, noise

I am reading a book named Learn Quantum Computing with Python and IBM Quantum Experience authored by Robert Loredo. When I tried to run the code on Chapter 11, I followed the instruction and wroted down the code:

```
# Import plot and match libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import the noise models and some standard error methods
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel
# from qiskit.providers.aer.noise.errors.standard_errors import amplitude_damping_error, phase_damping_error
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import amplitude_damping_error, phase_damping_error

# Import all three coherence circuits generators and fitters
from qiskit.ignis.characterization.coherence import t1_circuits, t2_circuits, t2star_circuits
from qiskit.ignis.characterization.coherence import T1Fitter, T2Fitter, T2StarFitter

# Generate the T1 test circuits

# Generate a list of number of gates to add to each circuit
# using np.linspace so that the number of gates increases linearly
# and append with a large span at the end of the list (200-4000)

num_of_gates = np.append((np.linspace(1, 100, 12)).astype(int),
                         np.array([200, 400, 800, 1000, 2000, 4000]))

# Define the gate time for each Idnentity gate
gate_time = 0.1

# Select the first qubit as the one we wish to measure T1
qubits = [0]

# Generate the test circuits given the above parameters
test_circuits, delay_times = t1_circuits(num_of_gates,
                                        gate_time, qubits)
# The number of I gates appended for each circuit
print('Number of gates per test circuit: \n', num_of_gates, '\n')

# The gate time of each circuit (number of I gate * gate_time)
print('Delay times for each test circuit created, respectively: \n',
      delay_times)
```

After I successfully generate the circuits, I added the amplitude damping error like:

```
# Set the simulator with amplitude damping noise

# Set the amplitude damping noise channel parameters T1 and Lambda
t1 = 20
lam = np.exp(-gate_time/t1)

# Generate the amplitude damping error channel
error = amplitude_damping_error(1 - lam)
noise_model = NoiseModel()
#print(error)

# Set the dampling error to the ID gate on qubit 0.
noise_model.add_quantum_error(error, 'id', [0])
```

Then I tried to execute this circuit on a simulator like:

```
# Run the simulator with the generated noise model
from qiskit import execute
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
shots = 200
backend_result = execute(test_circuits, backend, shots = shots,
                         noise_model = noise_model).result()
```

Then the results are plotted:

```
# Plot the noisy results of the largest (last in the list) circuit
plot_histogram(backend_result.get_counts(test_circuits[0]))
```

The graph I got is like:
[image]
Howerver, the correct one should be like:
[image]

It seems to me the amplitude damping error was NOT added to the NoiseModel successfully. I wonder if anyone can help me to figure out the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the amplitude damping error added to the `NoiseModel` successfully. The issue happens because the noisy gates are removed from your circuits before sending them to the backend.

When calling `execute` function without specifying the optimization level, level $1$ will be chosen by default<sup>[[1]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/execute.html)</sup>. That will make the transpiler remove the `I` gates from the circuit. For more details see [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14377/9474).

So, you need to set `optimization_level` to $0$ while calling `execute`:

```
backend_result = execute(test_circuits, backend, shots = shots,
                        optimization_level = 0,
                        noise_model = noise_model).result()
```